# How to make Proguard obfuscate using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, android-proguard

ProGuard is not doing a very complete job of obfuscating my Android project.  When I decompile my apk at decompileandroid.com I see that it is only changing the name of local temporary variables and nothing else.  It is not changing class names, variable names, method names, or anything else.

After reading the manual all of the optional commands seem to be telling it NOT to do something so I am left to think it should obfuscate everything by default.

my  build.gradle has the following...

> ```
> buildTypes {
>     release {
>         minifyEnabled false
>         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Neither of those two files exist is the project.  The project is as it was converted from Eclipse by Android Studio.

What am I missing.  Do I need to create those two files and put some proguard parameters in them - if so what.  I want maximum obfuscation.
Thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1):

> Set **minifyEnabled true** in order to turn on code shrinking, and
>   then **shrinkResources true** to turn on resource shrinking.

[Reference for the quote](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking)

Comment: Its obfuscation I'm concerned with right now.  I don't care about shrinking at this point.

Comment: Based on what I've read, I think minifyEnabled true does enable obfuscation also, but I've not tested that. Anyway try it.

Comment: **minifyEnabled true** obfuscates the code. For more info, read [this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking)

Comment: Setting minifyEnabled to true did cause Proguard to do a very complete obfuscation.  However the program now blows when I run it.  Now that its is so obfuscated it seems impossible to find the cause.